# Koma-Script: Adding margin for printing

Tags: fonts, margins, koma-script, printing, crop

For printing purposes I need to add 3 mm margin to all four sides.

**MWE #1**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{newpxtext}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

**What I tried so far**

I added

```
\usepackage[cam,width=216truemm,height=303truemm,center]{crop}
```

to my document which delivered the desired result...but it killed my fonts.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**MWE #2**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[cam,width=216truemm,height=303truemm,center]{crop} % kills my font

\usepackage{newpxtext}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

**My question**

How can I add 3 mm margin to all four sides without using the crop-package?

Comment: The geometry package provides a layout geometry which is independent  of the page geometry.  See page 6 of the manual.

Comment: No, the error was because of an outdated PDF viewer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in comments.